# Android background service multiple threads

Tags: android, multithreading

Is there any restriction that doesn't allow you to start an ArrayList of threads in a background service when the app is not running? 
i.e.

```
for(Thread t : listThread) {
    t.start();
}
```

I'm not able to do this when app is not running in foreground, but if i hardcode every single thread and start one by one it works.
i.e.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread() {.....};
t1.start();
Thread t2 = new Thread() {.....};
t2.start();
```

Edit:
Real implementation:

```
public class Work extends Thread {

@Override
    public void run() {
       log.d("test","running");
}
```

In service in onStartCommand

```
List<Work> listWork = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    Work w = new Work();
    listWork.add(w);
}

for(Work work : listWork){
    work.start();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more Code like the initialization of the arraylist

Comment: It should work in either way. Also offtopic, but the usual way to do this is to let Work  implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`, and submitting them to a [Thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)

Comment: I don't use Thread pool now, but I've tried to make Work Runnable instead of Thread but is not working...the strange thing is that when app is in foreground and service start it works. When app is not running (neither in background) service start, run onStartCommand but skip the start thread loop. No message on Android monitor, no exception arise